# GEO NODES : rotate according to geometry normals of an object

Tags: normals, geometry-nodes

I'm working on an Ivy geo nodes project
I draw curves onto a surface, it becomes the trunc and leaves are distributed along the curve.
I'd like to rotate the leaves according to the surface normals
Example: my curve is drawn on a cube from one face to the other and the leaves follow the cube's normals.
How should I do that?
PS : My Geo node modifier is on the Curve, not on the surface

---

RE: answer by [Crantisz](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/32374/crantisz) , maybe due to the fact that the leaves are spawned on a curve before.
I replaced the leaves by a cone so that you can see for yourself
[image]

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Normal it is a vector, not a rotation. So to get rotation from the normal, use align Euler to vector

Answer (score 3):

You can transfer values from object to object using transfer attribute. This is a simple setup, you may add some variety to the vector:

[image]

Of course this method has some limitations, but overall it produces good results.

Note: You shouldn't use normals as rotation, it's different things. Use align Euler to vector to convert normal to rotation